# Selecting text from ListView in c# windowsForms

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, controls

I'm coding in C#, in Windows Forms. I'm using VS 2013.

I have a `ListView` in detailed mode and it shows my data correctly. I want to select it's items and copy the text of them or show some information about an item when I hover the mouse over it. But I can't do anything with Data which are shown in table. Only the first column can be selected and of course I can't copy those items too. The other columns cannot be selected.

What should I do?
I've searched table in toolbox. But there is only `TableLayoutPanel` and working with it is harder than `ListView`. Does VS 2013 have anything better?

Comment: `listView1.FullRowSelect = true;`

Comment: consider using DataGridView if you need more flexibility. To overcome the limitation of selection only in the first column, set the "FullRowSelect" property to true in the listview's property sheet

Comment: Thanks. I know this about ListView. But this property doesn't give me the ability to select a separate house of table or copy it's data. I'm looking for something like table widget in Qt. but can't find something like that in VS 2013.

Answer (score 0):

One way to control mouse hover is by making a event for mouse hover

```
this.panel1.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.panel1_MouseHover);

private void panel1_MouseHover(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
    // Update the mouse event label to indicate the MouseHover event occurred.
    label1.Text = sender.GetType().ToString() + ": MouseHover";
    // Instead of printing you can do whatever you want here, like you want to select some text or whatever
}
```

For more details, you can see this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover(v=vs.110).aspx

For complete row selection, you can use

```
listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
```

Comment: Thank you about mousehovering tips. My main purpose is to select cells of the table.